# Oracle Data Change Notification

Tags: vb.net, oracle

Our VB.NET application uses Oracle Data Change Notification via ODP.NET V2.112.1.0

So far everything worked fine. However, after the Database Service was restarted, it stopped working and no notifications are being received any more. No GRANTS have been revoked or changes made in the database.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle keeps DCN listner information in user_change_notification_regs table which is created in temporary table space. Therefore when you restart the Database Service you have to re register the listners.